# Non-metric space resources

Tags: general-topology

I am not the greatest in math but I have a personal interest I would like to pursue and I believe non-metric spaces may be a useful tool in the process. But I am relatively unfamiliar with math... despite having taken vector calculus and doing well (B+) it's been a long long time.

I've looked up math dependency trees and I believe this lies within "Topology," but I want to be sure. I'm curious as to your opinions as to textbook recommendations. They need not be current... an "ol' staple" would be good as I could ask questions in forums regarding problems and likely have someone have experience with the book.

Lastly, for prerequisite areas to study I came across a math dependency tree indicating calculus... also set theory seems applicable. What other areas might be useful?

My interest to pursue: classification of objects using non-metric spaces.

Comment: Other than familiarity with elementary set theory, all you really need to study topology is an open mind.  For a book recommendation, I have to point you towards Munkres's *Topology*. It's great.

Comment: Everyone here will recommend Munkres' Topology, and there is good reason for that. If you're inexperienced in the ways of proof, you may find it difficult at first.  You should give serious consideration to an introductory proof text, like "How to Prove it."   If you're looking to get a taste, but you're not sure you want to spend a lot of money on a text like Munkres, you might want to get a book by Mendelson (it's dover). On the other hand, if you want something as comprehensive as Munkres in terms of foundational material, you might consider Willard's text.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely you are going to need Topology. A good book in my opinion is Topology by James Munkres. The book is not hard to read, and it goes step by step. In order to study Topology you do not need anything else. Of course, it is good if you have at least a course in Calculus because you can compare topological spaces with metric spaces, see the differences and so on.